How to disable 'Malicious app' warning?
Termux Screenshot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Android 14 OnePlus Pad 2 tablet via Termux app. It's partially installed and viewable via VNC. But 'apt install' or 'apt upgrade' causes a warning popup to be displayed which cancels the operations in background, as shown in the screenshot.

Security Warning "A malicious app attempted to damage your phone
system. We have stopped the app from doing this. We recommend
restarting your phone and uninstalling the app."

I have disabled phantom processes and flags already:
adb devices

adb shell "/system/bin/device_config set_sync_disabled_for_tests persistent"

adb shell "/system/bin/device_config put activity_manager max_phantom_processes 2147483647"

adb shell settings put global settings_enable_monitor_phantom_procs false

But still can't get past the issue
Has anyone faced this?

Also posted on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/1etlbnd/how_to_disable_malicious_app_warning/

There's the same issue posted on XDA Forums but without solution: Oppo Find x7 ultra keeps killing my Linux apps

@AndrewT. Yes. I figured that this is manufacturer specific issue, so posted in r/OnePlus. Now I have justed posted on r/termux. I don't have much hope, but let's see.
